# Pure javascript/ jquery solution to Angular's 'ng-repeat' function with data-attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a custom repeater function similar to Angular JS's `ng-repeat` to iterate over data. I want to do this purely with javascript/ jquery and make use of html `data-attributes`.

So for example, let's say I have this html

```
    <tr data-repeat="datas">
      <td data-repeat-value="data.name">--</td>
      <td data-repeat-value="data.email">--</td>
    </tr>
```

I'm wanting to create a function that's smart enough to see this html and map over however many `<tr>`'s and `<td>`'s it needs to and spit out the data correctly.

Without the data-attributes, a js solution would look this

```
    ${datas.map(data => 
        `<tr>
            <td>${data.name}</td>
            <td>${data.email}</td>
        </tr>`).join("")
    }`;
```

But how would I write the js to make use of the `data-attributes`?

I've got a [codepen](https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/gNmEKg?editors=0010) showing the working version without `data-attributes` along with a non-working version with `data-attributes`.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```js
getApiData(url, function(apidata){
    const $template = $('[data-repeat-new]');
    const $container = $template.parent();

    $template.remove();

    $container.append(
        apidata.map(data =>{
            const $snippet = $template.clone(true);
            $snippet.find('[data-repeat-value-new]').each((i, el) => {
                $(el).text(eval($(el).data('repeat-value-new')));
            });
            return $snippet;
        })
    );
});
```

Full example is here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JQWVGG?editors=0010 (the only change is in `// Not Working` block).

What it does:

- finds a DOM fragment which is going to be our template (one that matches `[data-repeat-new]` selector)
- stores a reference to parent element of that fragment -- the container where we're going to insert new content
- removes that fragment, as we don't want to see template in final output
- for each data element it does the following:

  - clones template
  - searches for all nodes that needs a value to be inserted (i.e. ones that match `[data-repeat-value-new]` selector)
  - and for every such node it replaces node's contents with evaluated expression (expression comes from value of `data-repeat-value-new` attribute, and we have `data` variable in  `eval`'s context, so, things just work)
- afterwards, all these cloned templates are appended to container

That `eval` call might look dangerous, so:

- you can make simple expression parser that will reduce possible expressions to some subset of JS, e.g. it could be able to only get elements from fixed array (i.e. expressions like `data.property` or `data.property[0]`)
- or you can leave it as is, because this eval happens on client side, and code source is DOM node -- if attacker can set arbitrary value in your DOM, he probably can execute any other code too

And a note re value of `data-repeat-new`: you get your API data in your code, and you never assign it, so, I'm not sure how one could interpret value of that attribute. One way would be provide some repository of data, where there are arrays with their names, like this:

```js
const repo = {
    data1: [{id: 'rec1'}, {id: 'rec2'}, {id: 'rec3'}]
};
```

And then in your code you could do this:

```js
const $template = $('[data-repeat-new]');
const $container = $template.parent();

$template.remove();

const data = repo[$template.data('repeat-new')];

$container.append(
    data.map(data =>{
        const $snippet = $template.clone(true);
        $snippet.find('[data-repeat-value-new]').each((i, el) => {
            $(el).text(eval($(el).data('repeat-value-new')));
        });
        return $snippet;
    })
);
```

Comment: This is fantastic! thank's a ton for your help with this. I really like your solution and I appreciate the breakdown

Comment: One more thing @alx , what if I wanted to use this in multiple places on the same page? I updated the [codepen](https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/xoqepE) to show you what i mean

Comment: Well, that last part -- "One way would be provide some repository of data" -- is exactly about this. Do you need help with that?

Comment: ohhh, i see what you mean. i can probably figure it out i just need to really look over your solution a bit more. i was thinking of possibly making the `data-repeat="repo"` *(or whatever is inside the quotations)* the unique identifier also. UI guy over here lol.. I'm so bad with data but I'm slowly learning

Comment: Just give it a try, because that’s how people learn new things — by trying. Let me know if you’re stuck.